# CodeIgniter News Tutorial - Delete and Update

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter, and I have followed the tutorial to make a news application. I am now on deleting and updating the news article but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I have come up with so far, but it doesn't work because when I click delete article in index all that happens is that I get an error message saying : `webpage cannot be found`.

news controller :

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

    public function view($slug)
    {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
        if (empty($data['news_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('news/create');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->news_model->set_news();
            $this->load->view('news/success');
        }
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        $this->news_model->delete_news($id);
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect('/news');
    }

}
```

news_model:

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function set_news()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
    }


    public function delete_news($id) 
    {
        $this->db->delete('news', array('id' => $id));
    }

}
```

index :

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
    <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
    <p><a href="news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>">delete article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use absolute path

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>">delete article</a>
```

also in your controller  after delete

instead of

```
redirect('/news');
```

use absulot path or you can simply write

```
$this->index();
```